# HTML event gives 'Uncaught TypeError: X is not a function'

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, typeerror

I had a problem. Here's the very simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function ended(e) {
            alert("Ended");
        }
        
        function paused(e) {
            alert("Paused");
        }

        function played(e) {
            alert("Played");
        }       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <video src="videoFile.mp4" controls onended="ended(event)" onpause="paused()" onplay="played(event)" >
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any time I paused, played, or ended the video, I would get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: played is not a function
    at HTMLVideoElement.onplay
```

or the same but with `paused` or `ended` instead of `played`, and `onpause` and `onended` instead of `onplay`.

I've already solved it, so I put the answer below, for those who encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `HTMLMediaElement`, which the `<video>` element is, contains some boolean properties: `ended`, `paused` and `played`.

And it turns out that when the browser (Chrome, maybe others) calls the event, it gets the value of those properties (which is `true` or `false`), instead of using my already defined functions. So then it tries to call `true(event)` or `false(event)`, and since `true` and `false` are not functions, it gives the error that `played is not a function`.

So the answer is, make sure that the function names you use for events do not match properties within the relevant HTMLElement that is firing the event, and then you shouldn't have any problems. (I haven't checked, but it seems likely this would occur with other HTMLElements)

In my case I changed them to `doMyEnded`, `doMyPaused` and `doMyPlayed` and all was well.

NOTE: I strongly recommend anyone who wants to know more about this read the answer by T. J. Crowder

Comment: I strongly recommend anyone who wants to know more read the answer by T. J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons **not** to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Not only can they only call global functions (which aren't best practice), but they run in a complicated scoping environment which includes not only the current element's properties (the problem you had) but in some cases properties from other elements as well (such as the `form` an `input` is located in). *(More below.)*

Instead, use [modern event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (and [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) when possible [all modern browsers support them]).

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <video src="videoFile.mp4" controls></video>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
        function ended(e) {
            console.log("Ended");
        }
        
        function paused(e) {
            console.log("Paused");
        }

        function played(e) {
            console.log("Played");
        }       

        const videoElement = document.querySelector(`video[src="videoFile.mp4"]`);
        videoElement.addEventListener("ended", ended);
        videoElement.addEventListener("pause", paused);
        videoElement.addEventListener("play", played);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

About the "complicated scoping environment": The code in an `onxyz`-attribute-style event handler runs in a scope that is effectively created like this (for your example):

```js
with (document) {
    with (theTargetVideoElement) {
        // ...your code here...
    }
}
```

(That's right, the dreaded (and deprecated) [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).)

For an element in a `form`, it's even worse:

```js
with (document) {
    with (theForm) {
        with (theTargetElementInTheForm) {
            // ...your code here...
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of that:

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input type="button" onclick="
        console.log(documentElement.tagName); // 'HTML'
        console.log(method); // 'post'
        console.log(type); // 'button'
    " value="Click Me">
</form>
```

- `documentElement` comes from `document`
- `method` comes from the `form` element
- `type` comes from the `input` element

Just Say No.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. I'll probably still be marking mine as the official answer because it's short and so people who 'just want it to work' will get that, but I've recommended anyone who wants to know more read this answer. Thank you so much!